# How to add link at chatbot in instagram from dialogflow

Tags: javascript, json, artificial-intelligence, instagram, dialogflow-es

I'm programming a chatbot using the dialogflow for instagram, and i'm trying to add a link for whatsapp in the conversation.
I tried to uso the custom payload, but all that i find in the internet is about integrate with facebook, i didnt found anything about instagram, someone could help me with some JSON or something like it?

The integration is between instagram and facebook, so i tried the follow json to solve my problem, but it didn't work

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "button",
        "text": "Clique no botão abaixo para enviar uma mensagem no WhatsApp:",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "type": "web_url",
            "url": "https://api.whatsapp.com/message/UWFGIHDLIDBYM1?autoload=1&app_absent=0",
            "title": "Enviar mensagem no WhatsApp"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```